# Dealing with unrealistic performance expectations

Tags: planning, software-development, performance

What facts and sources can I use to convince a manager I'm currently working with that rewriting a project of ~20'000 lines of code in a month is a completely unrealistic plan, and that writing ~5'000 lines of functional code in 3 weeks is actually a good result?

Comment: How about starting with how you arrived at your own estimates? Where's your supporting data for that?

Comment: @CodeGnome, just my subjective experience. That's why I'm asking for facts and sources.

Comment: Neither of you actually have supporting data, both figures are essentially made up. Ask if you can see how much you can deliver in a week and then extrapolate.

Comment: @Nathan Cooper, give such data to me, then. I don't mind if I'm proven wrong - with facts.

Comment: @XenoMind the point was to create your own data, because data from any other team is not your team and won't reflect reality *for you*.

Comment: @XenoMind and that reality is that no two teams will do the same work in the same amount of time.

Comment: @RubberDuck, and no two cars can cover the same distance on 1 liter of gas...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Acceptable SLoC Rates?](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/16082/what-are-acceptable-sloc-rates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A previous answer that I wrote here on Project Management Stack Exchange provides high/low/nominal values for source lines of code written based on project type per staff-month.](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/16084/30) More specific data is always better - using historical data from your past experiences or past projects at your company of similar size and scope - would be more relevant. As you can see from that data, even 5000 SLOC/staff-month is well outside of nominal ranges for every application type and size.

Answer (score 3):

There's more to estimating/evaluating a project than just the lines of code that need to be (or were) created/modified. Size and nature of the modification/addition, complexity of the code, code re-use, programming language, verbosity of the code (you can have one line do the exact same thing as five lines - and this may be good or bad depending on situation and opinion) and use of external packages, to name a few. And many of these will change, not just on a team-to-team basis, but on a *project-to-project* basis.

The only people who are really equipped to give any sort of reasonable and realistic estimation, given all of these factors, are the people who *actually do the work.* If a manager tries to estimate what is 'realistic', their estimate is going to be coloured by other factors - such as timelines and other constraints - which would falsify such estimates even if the manager *did* have the ability to otherwise properly estimate the work.

A more effective system is for the developers to make the estimate, the manager to *trust* the developer's *ability* to make estimates (if the manager does not, that is a separate problem that must be addressed), and then the manager must make a decision on whether the value added by the work is worth the estimated effort expended to accomplish it.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are talking about lines of code, you could check a popular github projects graphs to see how many lines are committed in similar time periods

https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/graphs/contributors

Comment: 1. Open source dev happens in spurts. 2. You referenced Microsoft, *Microsoft* as a benchmark? I'm willing to bet very few companies can match the churn rate MS does.

Comment: 1. you can check individual contributors who work on the project continuously for a period of time 2. again, check individual contributors to cancel out the effect of companies having more devs